# CMMotionManager returns big jump in yaw just after starting in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, core-motion

This is a function I didn't believe I had trouble with in iOS 6, but seem to be running into issues now in iOS 7. Each time I start my motion manager (using startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame), my motion handler invariably reports a big, nonexistant jump in yaw after about half a second. This only seems to occur when you use a reference frame of CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical or CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical. Is there any way to update CMDeviceMotionHandler in any way to compensate for it?

To illustrate, below is verbose output of each output attitude after starting my motion manager. Note how the yaw spontaneously jumps after about 0.5s.

```
2013-08-28 21:22:41.325 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 49.628127, Roll: 3.061527, Yaw: -1.420758
2013-08-28 21:22:41.366 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 49.567161, Roll: 2.539731, Yaw: -1.035483
2013-08-28 21:22:41.368 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 49.542753, Roll: 2.248727, Yaw: -0.822929
2013-08-28 21:22:41.370 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 49.475405, Roll: 2.006880, Yaw: -0.646478
2013-08-28 21:22:41.373 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 49.405571, Roll: 1.796121, Yaw: -0.490888
2013-08-28 21:22:41.375 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 49.331390, Roll: 1.644289, Yaw: -0.385082
2013-08-28 21:22:41.385 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 49.247448, Roll: 1.499398, Yaw: -0.293233
2013-08-28 21:22:41.400 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 49.169564, Roll: 1.375473, Yaw: -0.217664
2013-08-28 21:22:41.403 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 49.087577, Roll: 1.298058, Yaw: -0.170136
2013-08-28 21:22:41.416 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 49.016980, Roll: 1.253348, Yaw: -0.143872
2013-08-28 21:22:41.431 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.976531, Roll: 1.196151, Yaw: -0.101682
2013-08-28 21:22:41.434 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.958237, Roll: 1.156605, Yaw: -0.071089
2013-08-28 21:22:41.447 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.939612, Roll: 1.071295, Yaw: 0.002808
2013-08-28 21:22:41.462 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.903235, Roll: 1.020576, Yaw: 0.050194
2013-08-28 21:22:41.465 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.866325, Roll: 0.977751, Yaw: 0.089039
2013-08-28 21:22:41.477 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.835792, Roll: 0.952468, Yaw: 0.106070
2013-08-28 21:22:41.493 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.831971, Roll: 0.934805, Yaw: 0.116239
2013-08-28 21:22:41.496 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.843288, Roll: 0.920311, Yaw: 0.121559
2013-08-28 21:22:41.509 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.857048, Roll: 0.912051, Yaw: 0.118162
2013-08-28 21:22:41.526 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.863274, Roll: 0.898121, Yaw: 0.116690
2013-08-28 21:22:41.530 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.866083, Roll: 0.874281, Yaw: 0.123867
2013-08-28 21:22:41.541 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.863881, Roll: 0.835707, Yaw: 0.147356
2013-08-28 21:22:41.555 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.862856, Roll: 0.800074, Yaw: 0.168110
2013-08-28 21:22:41.559 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.872933, Roll: 0.765896, Yaw: 0.188365
2013-08-28 21:22:41.570 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.881562, Roll: 0.749693, Yaw: 0.200020
2013-08-28 21:22:41.586 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.876250, Roll: 0.728082, Yaw: 0.212002
2013-08-28 21:22:41.590 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.856920, Roll: 0.707687, Yaw: 0.219435
2013-08-28 21:22:41.601 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.840266, Roll: 0.678230, Yaw: 0.231034
2013-08-28 21:22:41.617 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.838389, Roll: 0.646075, Yaw: 0.248422
2013-08-28 21:22:41.621 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.846803, Roll: 0.606845, Yaw: 0.269967
2013-08-28 21:22:41.632 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.850193, Roll: 0.563535, Yaw: 0.290147
2013-08-28 21:22:41.648 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.854796, Roll: 0.521405, Yaw: 0.310114
2013-08-28 21:22:41.651 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.848840, Roll: 0.495401, Yaw: 0.320581
2013-08-28 21:22:41.663 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.847574, Roll: 0.476676, Yaw: 0.329254
2013-08-28 21:22:41.679 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.846378, Roll: 0.465281, Yaw: 0.323528
2013-08-28 21:22:41.682 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.871945, Roll: 0.459737, Yaw: 0.315833
2013-08-28 21:22:41.696 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.872580, Roll: 0.453971, Yaw: 0.314404
2013-08-28 21:22:41.710 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.860497, Roll: 0.439179, Yaw: 0.321968
2013-08-28 21:22:41.714 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.838540, Roll: 0.413087, Yaw: 0.342403
2013-08-28 21:22:41.726 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.828212, Roll: 0.394198, Yaw: 0.354884
2013-08-28 21:22:41.741 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.836743, Roll: 0.370267, Yaw: 0.366601
2013-08-28 21:22:41.744 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.839021, Roll: 0.342199, Yaw: 0.380237
2013-08-28 21:22:41.758 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.842708, Roll: 0.338735, Yaw: 0.370630
2013-08-28 21:22:41.772 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.837031, Roll: 0.350693, Yaw: 0.347981
2013-08-28 21:22:41.777 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.830125, Roll: 0.372368, Yaw: 0.326675
2013-08-28 21:22:41.787 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.828191, Roll: 0.375706, Yaw: 0.320968
2013-08-28 21:22:41.803 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.811894, Roll: 0.367849, Yaw: 38.517324
2013-08-28 21:22:41.807 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.804581, Roll: 0.339469, Yaw: 38.530965
2013-08-28 21:22:41.818 Déjà Vu[5675:60b] CMAttitude Pitch: 48.804247, Roll: 0.308285, Yaw: 38.546571
```

Comment: Can you see the same abrupt change when you print the content of [CMAttitude.CMQuaternion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMAttitude/quaternion)?

Comment: Yep, I do. I've added that output as an edit above.

Comment: OK, definitely a change of reported rotation and not just a transformation issue. If the demo project motion graphs shows reproducibly this peak too, you should file a bug. I start motion manager once in the initalisation phase and it appears to run stable afterwards

Comment: I really **don't** see the peak in the output of the MotionGraphs demo project (added above). There's some gradual easing of a dimension like the yaw, but that doesn't seem too unusual. Is there any way I could be initializing my motion manager wrongly?

Comment: Actually, I have realized that it is caused specifically by using a reference frame of CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical or CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical. Without a reference frame, the output is smooth and normal. With a reference frame, it introduces the jump, and this seems to have been introduced with iOS 7. I see the exact same jump if I change the MotionGraphs demo to use a reference frame, as well.

Comment: Another interesting point: I observed a significant performance drawback in iOS 7 in my app running on iPhone 4. Yesterday I updated to 7.0.3 and it almost disappeared. I am pretty sure that Apple has done a couple of changes to enable M7 activity monitoring and maybe there are some side effects. A similar situation occurred between 5.x and 6.x related to changing deviceMotionUpdateInterval (s. my blog)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of jump will always happen after a long period of sensors inactivity.

Just add to your log this value:

```
[[motionManager deviceMotion] magneticField].accuracy
```